# Given a sub-presheaf $(F,\alpha)\subseteq X$, how does one create subobjects $y_{A,x}\subseteq\scr{A}$ $(\cdot,A)$ for all $(A,x)\in\int_\scr{A}$ $X$?

Tags: solution-verification, category-theory, limits-colimits, topos-theory

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}\newcommand{\A}{\mathscr{A}}\newcommand{\psh}{\operatorname{Psh}}\newcommand{\set}{\mathsf{Set}}\newcommand{\op}{^{\mathsf{op}}}\require{AMScd}$The TLDR is: Given that we know what the subobject classifier looks like on representables, how can we prove it acts as a subobject classifier on all presheaves? I am close, but there is an encoding process that I have tried for a very long time to envisage, and I just can't (failed attempt below!). This is a long question because I am showing every process and piece of working in as much detail as is appropriate. If this is a duplicate in the sense that someone else has already demonstrated a subobject classifier for a presheaf category, by all means link the post, but this won't be a full duplicate unless they somehow mimic my approach exactly.

Question and approach:

Let $\A$ be a small category. I was tasked to identify the subobject classifier $\Omega$ in the presheaf category $\psh_\A=[\A\op,\set]$. Let $H_\bullet$ denote the Yoneda embedding $\A\hookrightarrow\psh_\A$: if such $\Omega$ were to exist, then by the Yoneda Lemma we would have: $$\Omega(A)\cong\psh_\A(H_A,\Omega)\cong\{\text{subobjects of $H_A$}\},\quad\forall A\in\A$$This is ok since $\psh_\A$ is well-powered in this case of $\A$ small. We need also to identify a contravariant arrow map.

> Given a subobject $(F,\alpha)\subseteq\A(\cdot,A)$ and $f\in\A(A',A)$, construct a pullback, giving the new objects arbitrary titles: $$\begin{CD}\Lambda(B)@>\tau_B>>F(B)\\@V\sigma_BVV@VV\alpha_BV\\\A(B,A')@>>f\circ(\cdot)>\A(B,A)\end{CD}$$Now for all $q\in\A(B,B')$, observe that, by naturality of $\alpha:F\implies\A(\cdot,A)$, we have: $$\alpha_B\circ F(q)\circ\tau_{B'}=(\alpha_{B'}(\cdot)\circ q)(\tau_{B'})=(\alpha_{B'}\circ\tau_{B'})\circ q=f\circ\sigma_{B'}(\cdot)\circ q:\Lambda(B')\to\A(B',A)$$So the arrows $\sigma_{B'}(\cdot)\circ q:\Lambda(B')\to\A(B',A')$ and $F(q)\circ\tau_{B'}:\Lambda(B')\to F(B)$ commute with the pullback square, hence there exists a unique arrow - call it $\Lambda(q)$ - $\Lambda(B')\to\Lambda(B)$ such that the following square (and the other one involving $\tau$) commutes: $$\begin{CD}\Lambda(B')@>\Lambda(q)>>\Lambda(B)\\@V\sigma_{B'}VV@VV\sigma_BV\\\A(B',A')@>>(\cdot)\circ q>\A(B,A')\end{CD}$$It is straightforward to see that this definition makes $\Lambda$ functorial, $\A\op\to\set$. Furthermore, as $\alpha$ is a monic natural transformation, it can be shown that each $\alpha_B$ is monic, and thus each $\sigma_B$ is monic as a pullback of a monic, finally giving $\sigma:\Lambda\implies\A(\cdot,A')$ as a monic natural transformation, hence a subobject. As subobjects are equivalence classes of these monics, the fact that pullbacks are only unique up to isomorphism is not a problem, and this definition is well-defined independent of the representative $(F,\alpha)$ for similar reasons.
>
> Then defining $\Omega(f)[(F,\alpha)]=[(\Lambda,\sigma)]$ through this construction will also clearly make $\Omega$ functorial, $\A\op\to\set$.

So we have a working definition of $\Omega$ that handles representables well. I think that, to demonstrate $\Omega$ as a general subobject classifier, we need to invoke the theorem of colimits of representables.

Take an arbitrary $X\in\psh_\A$ - define (for brevity): $$\E:=\int_{\A}X:=\text{the category of elements of $X$}$$And define $Q:\E\to\A$ by $(A,x)\mapsto A$ and $((A',X(p)x)\overset{p}{\to}(A,x))\mapsto p\in\A(A',A)$. It can be shown that the following colimit identity holds: $$X\cong\lim_{\to\E}H_Q:=\lim_{\to\E}(H_\bullet\circ Q)$$Since $\E$ is a small category as inherited from $\A$. Then, to verify $\Omega$ is a subobject classifier for $X$, I can try (using the representables preserve (co)limits theorem) to use the fact that $\Omega$ is a subobject classifier in general if and only if: $$\begin{align}\{\text{subobjects of $X$}\}&\cong\psh_\A(X,\Omega)\\&\cong\psh_\A(\lim_{\to\E}H_Q,\Omega)\\&\cong\lim_{\leftarrow\E\op}\psh_\A(H_Q,\Omega)\\&\cong\lim_{\leftarrow\E\op}\Omega(Q(\cdot))\\\tag{$\ast$}&\cong\{(y_{A,x})\in\prod_{(A,x)\in\E}\Omega(A):\Omega(f)(y_{A,x})=y_{A',X(f)x},\,\forall f\in\A(A',A)\}\end{align}$$

The task at hand is to construct such an element $(y_{A,x})_{(A,x)\in\E}$ for all subobjects $(F,\alpha)\subseteq H_A$ and to find an inverse of this process. I don't think there are any slick categorical tricks to help me here - I just had to manually try, fail, and eventually arrive at a workable solution. I think I have done this now, and present my solution below. **My questions are**:

1. How can we construct subobjects from data $(y_{A,x})_{(A,x)\in\E}\in(\ast)$, and visa versa?
2. Is there an easier way? This seems an unusual amount of work (the book the exercises are from does not usually set labour intensive problems)

This question originally featured a solution to $1)$. However, I've since realised that it is incomplete. Passing to a computer science analogy, it is too lossy; we cannot actually extricate well-defined subobjects from the encoding that I use (there is enormous double counting in my reconstruction process). I'll leave it below hidden as a spoiler (because it is not terribly relevant but it is evidence of an attempt). Furthermore, I did not anywhere need the limit criterion $\Omega(f)(y_{A,x})=y_{A',X(f)x}$.

**My main difficulty with this is thinking of a way to bijectively encode maps $F(A)\overset{\alpha_A}{\implies}X(A)$ into subobjects $S_x(B)\hookrightarrow\A(B,A)$**. How can we relate arrows *into* $\A(B,A)$ with elements $(A,x)$? My best attempt is the one left below, where I thought that defining a subset of $\A(B,A)$ by those arrows $p$ for which $\overline{x}_B(p)$ is in the image $\alpha_BF(B)$ - but this process actually leaves either entirely empty or entirely full subsets. I just cannot see a way to complete this diagram: $$\begin{CD}\\F(B)@>?>>\A(B,A)\\@V1_{F(B)}VV@VV\overline{x}_BV\\F(B)@>>\alpha_B>X(B)\end{CD}$$Where $?$ is dependent on $(A,x)$ fixed. $\overline{x}$ denotes the Yoneda isomorphism, which is the only conceivable way of turning elements $x$ into arrows involved with $\A(\cdot,A)$.

> Fix a presheaf $X\in\psh_\A$, a subobject $(F,\alpha)\subseteq X$ and $(A,x)\in\E$. I denote the Yoneda isomorphism with a bar: $\overline{(\cdot)}:X(\bullet)\to\psh_\A(H_\bullet,X)$. Define, for all $B\in\A$: $$S_x(B)=\{p\in\A(B,A):\overline{x}_B(p)\in\alpha_B(F(B))\}$$And for all $q\in\A(B',B)$ I claim that $S_x(q):S_x(B)\to S_x(B'),\,p\mapsto p\circ q$ is well-defined, since, by naturality: $$\begin{align}\overline{x}_{B'}\circ(p\circ q)&=X(q)\circ\overline{x}_B(p)\in X(q)(\alpha_B(F(B)))\\&=\alpha_{B'}(F(q)(F(B)))\\&\subseteq\alpha_{B'}(F(B))\end{align}$$This definition makes $S_x$ functorial and moreover $S_x(B)$ has the obvious injective inclusions into $\A(B,A)$ for all $B$, which define natural transformations by choice of $S_x(q)$, hence we may call $S_x$ a subobject of $H_A$.
>
>  Now consider any $f\in\A(A',A)$ - we want to verify the equation $\Omega(f)(S_x)=S_{X(f)x}$ up to isomorphism. However, due to the nice nature of the (anonymous) inclusion arrows, it is straightforward to verify that the following is a pullback square: $$\begin{CD}S_{X(f)x}(B)@>f\circ(\cdot)>>S_x(B)\\@VVV@VVV\\\A(B,A')@>>f\circ(\cdot)>\A(B,A)\end{CD}$$As soon as it is checked that the arrows are well defined. However, by the construction of the Yoneda isomorphism, $\overline{(X(f)x)}_B(p)=X(f\circ p)x=\overline{x}_B(f\circ p)$, so $\overline{(X(f)x)}_B(p)\in\alpha_B(F(B))$ implies $\overline{x}_B(f\circ p)\in\alpha_B(F(B))$ trivially. Thus, setting $y_{A,x}:=S_x$ for all $(A,x)\in\E$ gives us an element of $(\ast)$.
>
>  Now we need to go the other way. Take any $(y_{A,x})_{(A,x)\in\E}\in(\ast)$ and write the functor/transformation pairs as $(G_x,\beta_x)$. Define for $B\in\A$ the set: $$F(B)=\sum_{(A,x)\in\E}\overline{x}_B(\beta_{x,B}(G_x(B)))/\sim$$Where $\sim$ identifies equal elements (all the above disjoint components are subsets of $X(B)$). For $q\in\A(B',B)$ put $F(q)=\sum_{(A,x)\in\E}X(q)$ which by double naturality produces elements of $\overline{x}_{B'}(\beta_{x,B'}(G(q)(G_x(B))))\subseteq\overline{x}_{B'}(\beta_{x,B'}(G(B')))$ when acting on the $(A,x)$th disjoint component, so $F(q):F(B)\to F(B')$ holds. This definition obviously makes $F$ functorial, and moreover we have obvious inclusion transformations $F(B)\hookrightarrow X(B)$ by coalescing the disjoint components; since we took a quotient, these are injective inclusions. It remains to check naturality of these inclusions, but this is obvious by the definition of $F(q)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the set of objects $(A,x)$ of the category of elements $\int X$ of the presheaf $X$. The functorial nature of the presheaf is captured by the fact that any morphism $f\colon A\to B$ determines a function an element of the from $(B,x)$ to an element $(A,f^*x)$, in such a way that $g^*f^*x=(f\circ g)^*x$ and $\mathrm{id_A}^*x=x$.

In the case where $X$ is a representable functor, the element $(B,x)$ corresponds to a morphism $x$ with domain $B$, and $f^*x$ is literally the composition $x\circ f$, i.e. $f^*$ acts by pre-composition. Let's adopt this terminology for arbitrary presheaves and not just representables.

From this point of view, a natural transformation from another presheaf $Y$ to $X$ consists of functions sending $(A,y)\to(A,\alpha_A(y))$ so that $f^*\alpha_A(y)=\alpha_B(f^*y))$. We can say that the natural transformation is a function from elements of $\int Y$ to elements of $\int X$ that is invariant under pre-composition.

In particular, a natural transformation whose components are monomorphisms determines a subset of elements of $\int X$ that is stable under under pre-composition. Moreover, two such natural transformations are equivalent (as subobject of the presheaf $X$) if and only if they determine the same set of elements of $X$.

In the case where $X$ is representable, the subobjects of $X$ correspond to sets of morphisms with the same codomain (the representing object) that are stable under pre-composition. Call such a set a *sieve*.

The would-be subobject classifier $\Omega$ is a presheaf whose elements are sieves. The functorial structure is given  by specifying "pre-composition" on sieves. Explicitly, given a a morphism $f\colon A\to B$, the pre-composition with $f$ of a sieve of morphisms with codomain $B$ is the sieve of morphisms with codomain $A$ consists of all morphisms which when followed by $f$ result in a morphism in the sieve on $B$.

A natural transformation to the would-be subobject classifier $\Omega$ is then a precomposition-invariant function sending elements of $X$ to sieves. Thus the would-be subobject classifier is an actual subobject classifier if pre-composition stable sets of element of $X$ correspond to pre-composition invariant functions sending elements of $X$ to sieves.

Given a pre-composition invariant set of elements of $X$, for each element $(B,x)$ define the sieve of morphisms with codomain $B$ to be those $f\colon A\to B$ for which $(A,f^*x)$ is in the set.

Conversely, given a pre-composition stable function sending each element $(B,x)$ to a sieve on $B$, define the associated pre-composition stable set of elements to consist of those $(B,x)$ for which $\mathrm{id}_B\colon B\to B$ is contained in the sieve on $B$ associated to $(B,x)$.

Comment: Thank you for this. Annoyingly, my proposed solution which I put up a while ago was actually almost entirely correct - I just made an error in the reconstruction stage (i.e. your final paragraph)